# Text-align:center on only images in a table?

Tags: html, css

Im using a td.Image class that has text-align:center; to center images in a table i have.

It would be nice to not need to add the class on each td that has a image in it, and still be able to have normal align on other data, is this possible using only css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```